# RuntimeError: Could not run 'aten::to_dense' with arguments from the 'CPU' backend

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I iam trying to run a simple code as below.

I have features of two graphs of type sparse tensor, stored in a list

```
feature= [tensor(indices=tensor([[   0,    1,    2,  ..., 1896, 1897, 1898],
                           [   0,    1,    2,  ..., 1896, 1897, 1898]]),
           values=tensor([1., 1., 1.,  ..., 1., 1., 1.]),
           size=(1899, 1899), nnz=1899, layout=torch.sparse_coo), tensor(indices=tensor([[   0,    1,    2,  ..., 1896, 1897, 1898],
                           [   0,    1,    2,  ..., 1896, 1897, 1898]]),
           values=tensor([1., 1., 1.,  ..., 1., 1., 1.]),
           size=(1899, 1899), nnz=1899, layout=torch.sparse_coo)]
```

when I convert the feature above to dense tensor, i get the following result

```
print('this is feature 0', feature[0].to_dense())
print('this is feature 1', feature[1].to_dense())
this is feature 0 tensor([[1., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        ...,
        [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 1.]])
this is feature 1 tensor([[1., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        ...,
        [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

how ever when I do the same in the loop as below, i am getting surprising result

```
for i in range(2):
   feature=feature[i]
    print('these are new features: ',feature )
```

result to

```
tensor(indices=tensor([[   0,    1,    2,  ..., 1896, 1897, 1898],
                       [   0,    1,    2,  ..., 1896, 1897, 1898]]),
       values=tensor([1., 1., 1.,  ..., 1., 1., 1.]),
       size=(1899, 1899), nnz=1899, layout=torch.sparse_coo)
tensor(indices=tensor([[1]]),
       values=tensor([1.]),
       size=(1899,), nnz=1, layout=torch.sparse_coo)
```

and when I convert the same to dense tensor in the loop, like this

```
for i in range(2):
   feature=feature[i]
    print('these are new features: ',feature )
i get this error
RuntimeError: Could not run 'aten::to_dense' with arguments from the 'CPU' backend
```

What is the problem? how can I solve it? Any help will be much appeciated